# Why "abelian" is written frequently with a lower case initial letter while "Euclidean" exclusively with capital?

Tags: terminology

Why "abelian" is written frequently with a lower case initial letter while "Euclidean" exclusively with capital?

Look at the difference between [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is+euclidean%22&newwindow=1&rlz=1C1GCEU_huHU878HU878&sxsrf=AJOqlzVMNU8xnjAxyRNRv8v1CNDvMwZU4w%3A1673165305295&ei=-Xm6Y-vKEYH_7_UPzaadgAE&ved=0ahUKEwirq7C9wrf8AhWB_7sIHU1TBxAQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22is+euclidean%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIFCAAQkQIyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQ6CggAEEcQ1gQQsAM6BggAEAcQHjoICAAQBxAeEA86CAgAEAUQBxAeOgcIABCABBANOgcILhCABBANSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUOEFWJwfYN8kaAJwAXgAgAFbiAHjBZIBATmYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) and [that](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is+abelian%22&newwindow=1&rlz=1C1GCEU_huHU878HU878&sxsrf=AJOqlzV0mvKnINB4ALVYaUek9ntpsLT1kQ%3A1673165298276&ei=8nm6Y6q_EOfn7_UPmPKLoAc&ved=0ahUKEwiqgIS6wrf8AhXn87sIHRj5AnQQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22is+abelian%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIFCAAQgAQyBggAEB4QDzIGCAAQHhAPMgQIABAeMgQIABAeMgYIABAeEA8yCQgAEB4QDxDxBDIECAAQHjIGCAAQBRAeMgYIABAFEB46CggAEEcQ1gQQsAM6CAgAEIAEEMsBOgYIABAHEB46CQgAEAcQHhDxBDoICAAQBxAeEA86CggAEIAEEIcCEBQ6CwgAEAcQHhDxBBAKOgsIABAHEB4QDxDxBEoECEEYAEoECEYYAFC0tARYkL4EYLrDBGgFcAF4AIABW4gBlwSSAQE3mAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)